# Merge row values from the same value key in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Permission to ask, why is this the error? I try

```
select user_idea.idea_id,user_idea.title, idea_events.events, idea_categories.category_name AS category
from user_idea
LEFT join idea_events
on user_idea.idea_id=idea_events.idea_id
LEFT JOIN idea_categories
ON user_idea.idea_categories=idea_categories.category_id;
```

The result is sqliteonline like this:
[image]

I want to combine Dewasa and Anak events because of the same idea. For category why is the result NULL for values 1;2 not read in the idea_category table which should be Mudah; Sedang.
For table:

[image]

Output expected:
[image]

Comment: Please giving us the code you use to order and display the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_idea.idea_id,user_idea.title, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(events,';') FROM idea_events  Where user_idea.idea_id=idea_events.idea_id) as events, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category_name ,';') FROM idea_categories  Where user_idea.idea_categories=idea_categories.category_id) AS category
from user_idea;
```

Comment: yes this is work code, but i got problem in data where my data in user_idea column idea_categories with values 1;2 and 2;3 give me output NULL. I want to output as my output expected in question.

Answer (score 0):

1:2 idea_categories in user_idea is not considered as relevant to join so when joined it cannot find the data in other table here so data is null

reminder
**before doing join just analyse the data anomalies like not having common data and properly formatted**

Comment: and how to combine events for same indeks key?